# Weak function declaration inside header file

Tags: c++, arduino

how can i move the .cpp implementation of this function in the header?

```
.h
// function called on a valid IR event, must be overwritten by the user
void __attribute__((weak)) irEvent(IR_Remote_Data_t IRData);

.cpp
void irEvent(IR_Remote_Data_t IRData) {
// do things
}
```

I always had compiler errors that the function is redefined. with inline or not. Ive no idea how the right syntax is or if its even possible :S

Answer (score -1):

Just use:

```
void __attribute__((weak)) irEvent(IR_Remote_Data_t IRData) {
    // do things
}
```

and remove the definition from the `.cpp` file.

Comment: I tried that. but this only works if i dont overwrite the function. If i want to overwrite it it sais: ReceiveLedDemoDEVIR.ino: In function 'void irEvent(IR_Remote_Data_t)':
ReceiveLedDemoDEVIR.ino:41:6: error: redefinition of 'void irEvent(IR_Remote_Data_t)'
In file included from E:\Arduino\sketchbook\libraries\IRLremote/IRLremote.h:28:0,
                 from ReceiveLedDemoDEVIR.ino:21:
E:\Arduino\sketchbook\libraries\IRLremote/CIRLremote.h:86:28: error: 'void irEvent(IR_Remote_Data_t)' previously defined here
 void __attribute__((weak)) irEvent(IR_Remote_Data_t IRData){

Comment: @NicoHood There's no such a thing as "overwriting" a non-member non-virtual function. You *can* have a function declaration in the header and then *link* different implementation, though. For that you need to separate declaration and definition though (just like you have now).